# Printing in Android using WIFI printer

Tags: android, printing, wifi, airprint

I am implementing a scanner app.I have question how to print image in connection between android and printer directly such as AirPrint of IPhone.
 I heard that there is only way to print text and image using Google Cloud print in android. I am searching for any solution.but I cannot find any solution and example. 
Should I use any 3rd party tool to access WIFI printer in android?
Would you let me know any solution? so Anybody help must be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are targetting at the API level 4.4,Please refer the below link it will help you.[Printing with the Android Printing framework](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Printing_with_the_Android_Printing_Framework)

Comment: that is not what I want for the solution. I need roadmap or solution to make wifi printer App by using API, not external application and not API level 4.4. I want to customize print outs.

Comment: I think you should change your question. Otherwise the answer is a good fit to "how to print [an] image .. [with] android.